# How to calling the same Methods BUT different flow of the objects?

Tags: c#

I have 3 abstract classes (Customer, Tender, Site). For Customer has inherited class such as CorporateCustomer. For Tender has PreTender, InTender, PostTender concrete classes. Site has CorporateSite class.

I've already layout our the method, properties nicely, relationship between this objects and tested works well.

In MyTestApp implementation:

```
Customer customer = new CorporateCustomer(35); // ==> This will pass CustomerID = 35
string customerTenderName = customer.InTenders[0].Name; // ==> Customer has many Tender

Customer customer = new CorporateCustomer(35); // ==> This will pass CustomerID = 35
string customerSiteName  = customer.CorporateSites[0].Name;  // ==> Customer has many Site
```

Within my Site  also has implemented Get():

```
Site site = new CorporateSite();
List<Site> = site.Get(); // ==> This will return all sites
```

Now the issue is that I want to do the following as well with the same Get()

```
Customer customer = new CorporateCustomer(35);
List<Site>  = customer.CorporateSite.Get();  // ==> This will return all site belong to Customer (at this stage I don't know how to do this as yet)
```

As you can see because it's using the same Get() method how differentiate this without using like this GetByCustomer().

Is there any way somehow that you within the Get() i have a "checking" which one is relevant needs to be displayed based on the object/class is instantiate or something.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a Strategy that you can inject into the CorporateSite class (and other classes). The CorporateSite class then uses the Strategy to implement the Get method.

In this example I use a `Func<IList<Site>>` as the Strategy ([since delegates are excellent anonymous interfaces](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces.aspx)), but you can use an interface or abstract class instead if you would rather prefer that.

Imagine that you modify the CorporateSite class to take a Strategy as input:

```
public class CorporateSite
{
    private readonly Func<IList<Site>> get;

    public CorporateSite(Func<IList<Site>> getStrategy)
    {
        this.get = getStrategy;
    }

    public IList<Site> Get()
    {
        return this.get();
    }
}
```

If you have a good default implementation, you can add a constructor overload that uses a default Strategy, but I am leaving that as en exercise for the reader.

The point here is that the CorporateSite class itself does not implement the Get method but rather defers that implementation to the Strategy.

The Customer class can then inject the desired Strategy into the CorporateSite instance it exposes:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly CorporateSite site;

    public Customer()
    {
        this.site = new CorporateSite(this.GetSites);
    }

    public CorporateSite CorporateSite
    {
        get { return this.site; }
    }

    private IList<Site> GetSites()
    {
        // Put real implementation here
        return new List<Site>();
    }
}
```

Other classes that need to expose a CorporateSite can do the same while applying their own Get logic.

You can use the same pattern to implement other classes that need to have a Get method.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I know how to utilise the Strategy Pattern eventhough I am still cacthing up to understand this. This GetStrategy what is referring to?

Comment: The getStrategy variable is the Strategy that implements 'Get' functionality - hence the name.

Comment: The Get() method that is in CorporateSite is referring to collection of all sites? Where is the one that is referring to Get() (such customer.CorporateSite.Get()) for handling  sites collection for specific customer?!?!?

Comment: You mentioned that there is no implementation of the Get() in the actual CorporateSite and leave to other class that is using it. Now ... how about the Get() within the corporateSite iself to return all sites (corporateSite.Get()). How I am going to implement the Get() ??!!?

Comment: CorporateSite.Get() just returns the return value from the Strategy. The Customer class supplies a Strategy that returns the sites for the customer. Other classes that expose a CorporateSite can supply different Strategies.

Comment: Hi Mark. I am still don't understand this: corporateSite.Get() by itself return value form the Strategy BUT the strategy doesn't have any implementation at all. I can understand with the one for customer.CorporateSite.Get() or possibly in the future for corporate.Tender.CorporateSite.Get() for instance (meaning that list of site for specific tender and specific customer).

Comment: The Strategy can have any implementation you would like it to have. In my example, the Customer class defines this implementation as a call to the private GetSites method. In the example, this method doesn't really do anything, which is why I put the comment there. Other users/hosts of CorporateSite can supply their own Strategies that contains the implementation *they* would like it to have. Notice that the Strategy is a delegate, which means that it is a method that can be moved around. It could also have been an interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

how about `customer.CorporateSites` to return all sites of a customer?